# Is this head voice/mixed voice?

Tags: voice, falsetto

I have been a curious student of singing for a long time on my own now.
Basically scoured the Internet videos/forums, etc and practiced on songs that I like to cover.

The way I sing has consistently change with every new information/tip I discover from said media, I used to always(I'm pretty sure) pull chase only. Now the thing is I'm not sure if I have actually found my mixed or head voice yet. I no longer feel easily fatigued/tired much when singing the way I do today, but my tone is not something I'm a fan of. I'm hoping you guys can point me in the right direction. Like what I'm doing wrong,etc.

This is a cover of a 3 Days Grace song, Lost in You. In the Bridge section, I sing in what I myself call a mixed voice, though I'm not sure what it really is.
It just doesn't sound like my pure chest voice, which is why I call it mixed because it also doesn't sound like the pure operatic head voice, but then again, tone sounds quite disconnected to me. I'd like to improve on that part.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uy8695n4g9abfnj/Lost%20in%20You.mp3?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This may be a [duplicate](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/what-is-the-difference-between-male-head-voice-and-falsetto), in fact there are quite a few posts on this site about trying to sing head voice/falsetto. Consider seeing the other post and the good tips that are there.

From personal experience, I will say that the best learning mechanism for this is time. The other post gives technical descriptions of the voice mechanisms and explains that the voice needs to mature to help falsetto develop.

I developed an ok falsetto from singing a lot of rock and roll music, not that you should imitate other singers as much as you should hear how falsetto generally sounds and attempt it in your voice, not as an imitation of theirs.

Just a friendly reminder, singing too high can damage your voice. Don't strain out high notes, sing what is comfortable. If you want to improve your upper range hoot like an owl very high.

Answer (score 0):

I applaud the work you've been doing.  Making music is one of the things that keep us human!

I would suggest that you start to work with a teacher.  There are so many things a teacher can help you discover.  Learning to sing without a teacher is kind of like learning a foreign language just from a dictionary, without any interaction or conversation with other people in the target language.

The various parts of a singer's range that you have read about make sense in a trained voice, a voice that is doing things right.  They don't necessarily make sense in an untrained voice; and even in a trained voice, one would need to hear the full range in order to describe the voice, say where its break points currently are, and make targeted suggestions for the particular singer.

You have lots of talent and interest in music.  To channel the talent and interest optimally, you would need the help of an experienced vocal teacher.

Answer (score 0):

One does not "discover" mixed voice.  Mixed voice replaces the flip from chest voice to falsetto with a controlled transition.

Head voice is basically the chest-falsetto see-saw still on the chest voice side, just with most of the weight taken off.  It doesn't forego the flip but diminuishes its strength, and it takes overall strain off.  That's something you can develop gradually.  "pure operatic head voice" sounds like you are just throwing words around.  You should not try planning an exercise regimen based on words.

It makes more sense to work with a teacher for developing your voice, assuming that your aim is developing your voice rather than your terminology.